# Como popular um Spinner a partir de dados retornados de uma URL?

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte código que funciona bem, porem com um exemplo de *array*:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String...urls) {

    try {
        Log.e("****** MESSAGE ******", " Json Object  = " + JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList"));
        //  
        //  por favor note que, já consigo pegar os JSON da URL sem problemas! como no exemplo: <br>
        // REOTORNO DO JSON:
        // {"ReportRetryNumber":4,"ReportDetailTextList":["alfa","beta","gama","yota","zeta"]}

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


// TEST: Temporaly list
List < String > categories = new ArrayList < String > ();
categories.add("aaa");
categories.add("bbb");
categories.add("ccc");
categories.add("ddd");
categories.add("eee");
// Adapter Creation
dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

return false;
}
```

Tentei converter para trabalhar com o JSON e meu código ficou assim:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String...urls) {

    try {
        Log.e("****** MESSAGE ******", " Json Object  = " + JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList"));
        //  
        //  por favor note que, já consigo pegar os JSON da URL sem problemas! como no exemplo: <br>
        // REOTORNO DO JSON:
        // {"ReportRetryNumber":4,"ReportDetailTextList":["alfa","beta","gama","yota","zeta"]}



        List < JSONObject > categories = new ArrayList < > ();

        jsonarray = (JSONArray) JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL).get("ReportDetailTextList");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

          jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

          categories.add(jsonobject);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Adapter Creation
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    return false;
}
```

Acontece que não estou conseguindo colocar os dados da URL no meu `Spinner`,

por exemplo,  a linha:

> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);

Acusa um erro na variável *categories* ...

**Então aqui vai minha pergunta:**

- 1) Como ler corretamente o json?
- 2) Como colocar os dados no spinner?

Obrigada!

Comment: Camila! Voltei! Você tem que colocar na sua pergunta como é a estrutura do seu JSON.

Comment: BEM VINDOOO... . RSRSR bom, coloquei no comentario _"{"ReportRetryNumber":4,"ReportDetailTextList":["alfa","beta","gama","yota","zeta"]}"_

Comment: mas soh um detalhe, o erro. assim de inicio... parece estar na linha _**dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categories);**  pois a var  **categories**  fica vermelho e nao eh aceito...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de definir sua lista como model `<JSONObject>`, você vai trocar para `String`, que neste caso seria uma lista de *strings*.

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
```

Logo abaixo você a princípio faça desta forma, para verificar se está listando os dado da estrutura retornada do servidor corretamente. Veja:

```
String str = "{\"ReportRetryNumber\":4,\"ReportDetailTextList\":[\"alfa\",\"beta\",\"gama\",\"yota\",\"zeta\"]}";

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);
JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ReportDetailTextList");

for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
    categories.add(array.get(i).toString());
}
```

Para finalizar, se seu `JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl( URL ).get("ReportDetailTextList");` realmente estiver retornando um array, é só fazer desta forma abaixo:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl( URL ).get("ReportDetailTextList");
```

O código completo dentro do seu *try catch* deve ficar desta forma abaixo::

```
try{
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl( URL ).get("ReportDetailTextList");

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
        categories.add(array.get(i).toString());
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: bom nao deu nenhum erro, e rodou bonitinho!

Comment: To editando, com a parte final.

Comment: esqueci de falar...  pra funcionar, eu tive que comentar a linha: **dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, categopries);**

Comment: categopries? categopries? O que ser "categopries" ?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52776/resolvendo-json